# Predictions using AUC metrics for multilabel classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multilabel-classification

I'm using AUC metrics to do a multilabel classification. Since keras has removed prediction_classes for obtaining the prediction classes, I just use a threshold of 0.5 to get the output classes. However, as I understand, for AUC the threshold should not be 0.5 for an imbalanced data set. How can I get the threshold that was used for training the model?

Besides, I know that AUC is used for binary classification. Can I just use it for multilabel problem? How to calculate the threshold? By taking the average or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **AUC** for the multi-label problem, check [this](https://keras.io/api/metrics/classification_metrics/#auc-class).

```
import numpy as np 
y_true = np.random.randint(0,2,(100,4))
y_pred = np.random.randint(0,2,(100,4))

m = tf.keras.metrics.AUC(multi_label=True, thresholds=[0, 0.5])
m(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
```

FYI, from [`tf 2.5`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases), it now supports logit predictions.